# All of columnar values of Pandas dataframe in first column, how to extract to correct columns

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am dealing with a messy csv with several columns. Some of the rows have all of the column values in the first column, like so:

```
    City Edition Sport Discipline Athlete   NOC Gender  Event Event_gender  Medal
330 Paris,1900,Cricket,Cricket,"ROQUES, F.",FRA,Men,cricket,M,Silver    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
331 Paris,1900,Cricket,Cricket,"SCHNEIDAU, A.J.",FRA,Men,cricket,M,Silver   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
332 Paris,1900,Cricket,Cricket,"TERRY, Henry John",FRA,Men,cricket,M,Silver NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
333 Paris,1900,Cricket,Cricket,"TOMALIN, P.H.",FRA,Men,cricket,M,Silver NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
334 Paris   1900.0  Croquet Croquet AUMOITTE    FRA Men double  M   Gold
```

The first four rows have all of the values under the `City` column, whereas the last row has the correct values across the respective columns. There are a few hundred thousand rows and almost all of them have the column issue. I have to keep all rows with the correct values as is.

**EDIT**

My csv_read is fine, the file itself is the problem. The rows that causing problems are inside quotation marks and the athlete names are inside quotes with an apostrophe separate last and first name. So I guess the best thing to do is to create a function to open the file that will strip the extra characters. Though this could be hard to pull off without using lots of memory, as there are 300k rows...

Comment: Your delimiter or file are messed up.  You need to show  the file contents and the `pd.read_csv` statement

Comment: @piRSquared I have edited my post. The csv contents are the problem so I need to edit them to make the dataframe correct

Comment: @Wiseface You may be able to create a data frame by using the solution suggested by me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data need a complex regex pattern to be processed as follows:

```
# conda install -c conda-forge regex
import regex as re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_path = "data/mixed_csv.csv"
    # python re does not support for a variable-width lookbehind 
    pat = re.compile(r'\s+(?=(?:"[^"]*?(?: [^"]*)*))|\s+(?=[^",]+(?:,|$))|,(?=(?:"[^"]*?(?: [^"]*)*))|,(?=[^",]+(?:,|$))')
    refined_lines = ""
    with open(input_path, "r") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            tokens = pat.split(line)
            refined_lines += ",".join(tokens)
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(refined_lines), sep=",", index_col=0)
    print(df)
```

Basically, you need to understand look-ahead, look-behind regex patterns.

1. `regex1(?=(regex2))` : Positive Lookahead : matched regex1, then regex2 is matched
2. `regex1(?!(regex2))` : Negative Lookahead : matched regex1, then regex2 is not matched
3. `(?<=(regex2))regex1` : Positive Lookbehind : matched regex2, then regex1 is matched
4. `(?<!(regex2))regex1` : Negative Lookbehind : regex2 is not matched, then regex1 is matched

Result:

```
      City  Edition    Sport Discipline            Athlete  NOC Gender    Event Event_gender   Medal   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
id                                                                                                                                          
330  Paris   1900.0  Cricket    Cricket         ROQUES, F.  FRA    Men  cricket            M  Silver NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
331  Paris   1900.0  Cricket    Cricket    SCHNEIDAU, A.J.  FRA    Men  cricket            M  Silver NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
332  Paris   1900.0  Cricket    Cricket  TERRY, Henry John  FRA    Men  cricket            M  Silver NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
333  Paris   1900.0  Cricket    Cricket      TOMALIN, P.H.  FRA    Men  cricket            M  Silver NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
334  Paris   1900.0  Croquet    Croquet           AUMOITTE  FRA    Men   double            M    Gold NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Notes:

1. You should add some column names at the first line (`id`, those for `NaNs`)
2. You can process each `tokens` object per line instead of creating a dataframe if your memory is insufficient.

Comment: I got the following error when trying to implement above ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1204: character maps to <undefined>```

Comment: @Wiseface It is not about your original question. You should choose either `encoding='iso8859'` or `encoding='utf8'`. I do not know which one will work since I do not know the encoding of your input data. I think that you can solve your original question by my first answer. If so, I would appreciate it if you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `usecols` columns [padas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
 pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['City', 'Edition', 'Sport', 'Discipline', 'Athlete','NOC','Gender','Event','Event_gender','Medal'])
```

Comment: The issue is the csv, unfortunately, so I'll have to clean the contents while loading through a function